# Prevent constructor from getting called multiple times React

Tags: reactjs, pagination

In my use case: I am doing pagination where by I recieve the data only in my first call to the api in my subsequent paginated calls I am only receiving the pagination data.

How do I preserve my previous data in React Component as I am re rendering the Component again hence constructor is getting called

**My Code:**

```
    componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(getSettlementDetails(this.state.settlementParams));
}

componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
  if(!_.isEmpty(this.props.settlementData) && this.props.settlementData.totalTransactions) {  
   this.settlementData = this.props.settlementData
  }
}

render() {
    let pageDetails = {
        innerPage: true,
        tab: 'Settlements',
        breadCrumbData: [{
            tab: 'Settlements',
            url: 'settlements/'
        }, {
            tab: 'Details',
            url: 'settlements/'+this.props.params.id
        }]
    }

    let downloadProgress;

    /**
    * This is to show or hide download progress
    */
   if(this.props.excelQueue.exportFilterData.showDownloadProgress) {
       downloadProgress = (<DownloadProgress/>)
    }

    if(_.isEmpty(this.settlementData)) {
      this.settlementData = this.props.settlementData
    }

    if (this.props.settlement.fetching) {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header pageDetails={pageDetails}/>
                <div class="main-container">
                    <div>
                       Loading.....
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    } else if(this.props.settlement.fetched){
        return (
            <div>
                <Header pageDetails={pageDetails}/>
                <div class="main-container">
                    <div>
                        <SettlementDetail settlementDataPagination={this.props.settlementData} settlementData={this.settlementData} transactionList={this.props.settlementData.transactionListForSettlementDetailDTOListV1}
                        downloadFile={this.download.bind(this)} dispatchMethod={this.callPaginationApi}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {downloadProgress}
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header pageDetails={pageDetails}/>
                <div class="main-container">
                    <div>
                     No Data
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }



}
```

Right now I am storing the previous values in `this.settlementData` however the PaginationComponent re calls the `constructor` inside it

Comment: Have you looked at `prevState` yet? (see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: How will that help me here?

Comment: You need a state object within the constructor of the parent component to track this — `this.settlementData` in your case (which I assume precedes the code you have posted). It should look like this, though: `this.state = { settlementData: {} }`. Then inside the method that fires when a user advances to the next page, you modify `this.state` with `this.setState((prevState, props) => ({ settlementData: {} })`. I would have made an official answer but I need a fiddle that I can work with to really see what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution would be to store the state in the parent component. For example.

In your parent component declare field to hold states of the children that can be restored:

```
controlStates = {};
```

In your child component accept reference to parent component in props (or get it via [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) if you do not want to store sttes in the immediate parent).

Then you can restore your state in constructor:

```
if (!!props.parent)
{
    this.state = props.parent.controlStates[props.id];
}
```

and in componentWillUnmount or componentDidUpdate save it:

```
if (!!this.props.parent)
{
    this.props.parent.controlStates[this.props.id] = this.state;
}
```